# How to make a Transition in the same page with JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a simple app with news (I will get the news within a JSON file), there will be only one page, and on this page the user just need to slide to see the next news, Is that possible with JQueryMobile ??

I'm new Web mobile, so I just need an idea on how can I start ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pagecontainer widgets change method: **http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change**

Make sure to set the `allowSamePageTransition` property to true.